# MATLAB(linux) cannot find the gcc

Tags: c, linux, matlab, gcc

I try to compile in MATALAB, but it seems that the MATLAB cannot find the gcc:

```
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/glnxa64.

Error in compile (line 439)
mex(args{:});

>> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'gcc' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
you will be required to update your code to utilize the
new API. You can find more information about this at:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
mex -setup C++ 
mex -setup FORTRAN
```

But I have already installed the gcc using `apt-get install gcc`, and type the `gcc -v` can get the following information:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message tells you to go to http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/glnxa64, which lists **gcc 4.7.x** as a supported compiler, but you have 4.8.2

Comment: @m.s. should probably repost as answer.

Answer (score 0):

*converting my comment into this answer:*

The error message tells you to go to http://mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/glnxa64, which lists gcc 4.7.x as a supported compiler, but you have 4.8.2.

So you need to install GCC 4.7. On Ubuntu this can be done using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```